# get string before and after specific character

Tags: javascript

I want to split a string for a fill in string type with no whitespace for examples:

`£____`

`____$`

`42____$`

i would like a way to split the string so i can know what the characters before and after _.

Desired results:

```
`£____` => before = '£', after = null
`____$` => before = null, after = '$'
`42____$` => before = '42', after = '$'
```

I though of tried using word.replace('_', ' ') to split by whitespace but it returning the same string as the old one(i'm still a novice at javascript).

Comment: `str.split(/_+/)`

Comment: @Yousaf thank for the quick answer, i forgot regex can do so much more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a regex string split here:

```js
var inputs = ["£____", "____$", "42____$"];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    var parts = inputs[i].split(/_+/);
    console.log("before = " + parts[0] + ", after = " + parts[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Regex.

Something Like This

```
[^_;]
```